# Typescript SetStateAction<Data | null>' after async function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm in the process of learning typescript and it seems like I'm facing an issue that I couldn't get rid of despite all the attempts I've made so far.

Though the function works and does pull the data and everything seems to work on the frontend but in my VSCode it seems like there's red underlines.

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../utils/supabase";

export default function Home() {
  interface Data {
    paper_title: string;
    paper_description: string;
    prevState: null;
  }
  const [name, setName] = useState<Data | null>(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from("papers").select(`*
  `);
    if (data) {
      setName(data);
      console.log(data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <div>Check Console</div>;
}
```

[image]
Error:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<Data | null>'

I would like to understand why data is underlined as red and how can I pass object this data to the usestate?

Comment: Red lines where? What do the red lines say?

Comment: Hover over `data`, what is its type and what is the error in the popover?

Comment: This is the error I get: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Data | null>'

Comment: Ok. Are you certain the shape of this Data is that of the interface `Data`? I.e. have you verified this manually using console.log?

Comment: @adsy except the prevState, Yes. But I haven't added all the data from the table, should I do so?

Comment: You could use a type assertion here like `as` to make it be `Data` rather than `any`. However, this would be unsafe. You typically want the types to be generated from your back end schema. I would adopt https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/typescript-support. With this solution, anytime you do a `from()` call, the returned type will be guaranteed.

Comment: @adsy I went through the page now, but not sure how to implement it to my logic.

Comment: Basically, you are one step too far ahead. You need to configure your entire supabase client for TypeScript by setting up the command line scripts in your project and creating a supabase instance from the generated types. You need to follow this first, then all will become clear since everytime you do `from()` the `Data` will be typed exactly as it is in your database for that query.

Comment: If you want you can create a new state item `const [data, setData] = useState<Data[] | null>(null)` (`name` doesn't make sense as a name, and also it has a string in it and your data will be a list of rows) and then force it in by doing `setData(data as Data[])`. However, at that point, you surrendered the type-safety to the point that even using TS is questionable since you are telling TS what it is, rather than TS knowing what it is. Basically, inverts you back to human error and the possibility of runtime failures caused by basic mistakes.

Comment: @adsy I guess, I have to do the command line setup for now and take it from there.
Thank you for details and the walk throughs.

Comment: Once you've done it, you will no longer need the `interface Data` in your code as it will already be correct on the `from()` call. At that point, you should wrap just the `await supabase.from("papers").select(`*`);` line in a new function called `getPapers()`. Then you can create a new state item `const [ data, setData  ] = useState<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getPapers>>([])`. When you set this data into there it will just work and notice at no point did you even provide the properties themselves :), it will already know. So `data[0].paper_title` will magically be there and the right type.